# How to map a child with automapper and convert using

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I am using automapper to map from model to dto. In my model I want to use a string where in my dto I use an Enum. While it is a nested child, I am using ForPath instead ForMember. To convert to string is easy, however to convert the string back to type I wrote a ValueConverter. Using a ValueConverter in combination with ForMember is working excellent, however now I need to use it with ForPath which is not possible. Are there any other solutions to solve this problem, while I cannot find it in the automapper documentation or on stack.

This is my MappingProfile
this part is working with member:

```
CreateMap<Dto, Model>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Type.ToString()))
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.ConvertUsing(new StringToEnumConverter<Type>(), src => src.Type));
```

this part I need ForPath and ConvertUsing, this code is not allowed

```
    CreateMap<Dto, Model>()
            .ForPath(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Parent.Type.ToString()))
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForPath(dest => dest.Parent.Type, opt => opt.ConvertUsing(new StringToEnumConverter<Type>(), src => src.Type));
```

and this is my ValueConverter:

```
public class StringToEnumConverter<T> : IValueConverter<string, T> where T : struct
{
    public T Convert(string source, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        {
            if (Enum.TryParse(source, out T result))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return default;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can always avoid `ForPath` by creating a map for the inner object.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu But that is not possible while it are not 2 separate objects

Comment: Really? :) Then what is `Parent`?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu We can map both parents, however we only need 1 property from the parent and not the complete parent, so we choose to work with ForPath, otherwise we have to much in our model. So in model it is not a separate object just 1 property

Comment: `ForPath` doesn't support converters (unless you want to implement that yourself). So you either use `MapFrom` instead or drop `ForPath`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks for getting me on the right track. I am using mapfrom with a static class which converts to Enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Lucian Bargaoanu I came up with this solution. I rewrote the valueConverter to be just a static class and use MapFrom to convert.

```
 public static class StringEnumExtension
{
    public static TaskType ToTaskType(this string source)
    {
        return ToEnum<TaskType>(source);
    }

    public static TaskQuestionType ToTaskQuestionType(this string source)
    {
        return ToEnum<TaskQuestionType>(source);
    }

    private static T ToEnum<T>(string source) where T : struct
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        {
            if (Enum.TryParse(source, out T result))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return default;
    }
}
```

And I updated the mapping like this:

```
CreateMap<TaskDto, TaskModel>()
            .ForPath(dest => dest.TaskType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TaskDefinition.TaskType.ToString()))
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForPath(dest => dest.TaskDefinition.TaskType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TaskType.ToTaskType()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer additional maps within the same profile over using `ForPath`. This way I can still use my custom value resolvers:

```
public class DstObject
{
    public int AnotherProperty { get; set; }
    public DstChildObject DstChildObject { get; set; }
}

public class DstChildObject
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }      
}

public class MyMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MyMappingProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<SourceType, DstObject>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.AnotherProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AnotherProperty))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.DstChildObject, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
            ;

        this.CreateMap<SourceType, DstChildObject>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.SomeProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeProperty))
            ;
    }
}
```